# Como exibir apenas a primeira linha d'uma tabela?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho uma tabela com resumos sobre determinado cliente, onde a primeira linha é o principal conteúdo a ser exibido, e o restante é um mero complemento.

Sei que poderia aplicar `display: none`, mas acredito que não deva ser a melhor forma a ser feito. Quero ocultar o restante das `<tr>` e exibí-las com o `toggle`, que já está sendo feito:

```
$('#toggle-posicao-financeira').click(function() {
        $('#table-posicao-financeira').fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Veja o exemplo usando o seletor `:not(first-child)` para manipular apenas as demais linhas.

- **CSS**: `tr:not(:first-child)` - Manipular todas as linhas da tabela que não sejam a primeira.
- **Jquery** `tr:not(:first-child)` - Realiza o evento apenas nas linhas que não sejam a primeira.

```js
$('#mostrar').on('click', function() {
  $('table tr:not(:first-child)').toggle();
});
```

```css
table tr:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="mostrar" href="javascript:void(0)">Mostrar detalhes</a>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Arth</td>
    <td>90</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```